# Android Volley RequestFuture + RxJava2 Observable repeat

Tags: android, rx-java

In *MainActivity*, I want to refresh *toolbar* every 5 seconds.
So I implemented it with **Timer** & **Volley** Async request and it worked like a charm.

Now I prefer to replace Timer with **RxJava2**.
therefore I did these steps:

1. I changed Async Volley request to **RequestFuture**
2. in View, I changed Timer to Observable with repeat() method

But my problem is:
On each time that RX do repeat emitted data is same as the first one. 
WHY?

```
public Observable<String> doLiveRefresh2() {
    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    VolleyStringRequest request = new VolleyStringRequest(Request.Method.POST
            , REFRESH_URL
            , future
            , future) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return getRefreshParams();
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    return Observable.fromFuture(future, Constants.VOLLEY_SECONDS_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io());
}
```

---

```
final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
Observable<LiveResponse> observable = new LiveRemoteModel().doLiveRefresh2()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(Constants.TOOLBAR_BADGES_REFRESH_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .map(LiveResponse::new)
                ;

        DisposableObserver<LiveResponse> disposableObserver =
                new DisposableObserver<LiveResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull LiveResponse liveResponse) {
                        setToolbarBadges(liveResponse.getToolbarBadges());
                    }

                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("RX", "onError: ", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("RX", "onComplete: ");
                    }
                };

        Disposable disposable = observable.subscribeWith(disposableObserver);
        disposables.add(disposable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `repeatWhen` will repeat the *values*, and will not resubscribe. For that you need a slightly more complex construct:

```
Observable<LiveResponse> observable = Observable
            .interval(Constants.TOOLBAR_BADGES_REFRESH_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(dummy -> new LiveRemoteModel().doLiveRefresh2())
            .map(LiveResponse::new)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ;
```

Comment: When I **Dump** java heap, I found instance of *LiveRemoteModel()* increase.  What can I do for better memory performance?

Comment: Don't re-create them, and don't forget to *complete* the observable from doLiveRefresh()....

Comment: <Don't re-create them -> Do you mean Observable or LiveRemoteModel() ?
  I create Observable in *onResume()* so it created one time.But how can I not creating LiveRemoteModel() ?

Comment: What the lifetime of the `new LiveRemoteModel().doLiveRefresh2() ` observable? does it ever complete? How many items does it emit?

Comment: I create a new Question,please continue in it:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002734/android-rxjava2-memory-performance)