# Android RXJava2 memory performance

Tags: android, heap-memory, rx-java2

I created an Observable(RxJava2 + Volley) that repeat for each 5 seconds,
It works but when I **Dump** Java Heap(memory),there are many Instance of my *Model* JAVA class,and it will increase for each time that the Observable get repeating.
Why RX create several instance of my model? How can I use only ONE instance of it?

**Model**

```
public RequestFuture<String> getLiveRefreshFuture() {
        RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        VolleyStringRequest request = new VolleyStringRequest(Request.Method.POST
                , REFRESH_URL
                , future
                , future) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return getRefreshParams();
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        return future;
    }
```

---

**Activity**

```
    private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

final LiveRemoteModel model = DaggerLiveComponent.builder().build().getModel();

        Observable<LiveResponse> observable = Observable
                .interval(Constants.TOOLBAR_BADGES_REFRESH_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(dummy -> model.getLiveRefreshFuture())
                .map(RequestFuture::get)
                .map(LiveResponse::new)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        DisposableObserver<LiveResponse> disposableObserver =
                new DisposableObserver<LiveResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull LiveResponse liveResponse) {
                        setToolbarBadges(liveResponse.getToolbarBadges());
                    }

                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("RX", "onError: ", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("RX", "onComplete: ");
                    }
                };

        disposables.add(observable.subscribeWith(disposableObserver));
```

[image: Memory Dump]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why RX create several instance of my model? How can I use only ONE instance of it?

If you look carefully the object in the heapdump is `LiveRemoteModel$2` which indicates it is an anonymous class within `LiveRemoteModel`.

Looking at your code this is probably the `VolleyStringRequest` object that gets created each time `model.getLiveRefreshFuture()` is called. There is nothing retaining that object within the RX pipeline so there must be something within Volley retaining it.

Comment: It's maybe useful for someone 
I Convert all local variables to **WeakReference** and also I install **LeakCanary** library to monitoring leaks of memory. 
At least now all thing is OK.And All instance of *LiveRemoteModel* free up as soon as GC-event